# Excel 2013 message "Linking: file.xlsx. Press Escape to cancel."

Tags: microsoft-excel

When opening a specific file I get the message:

```
LINKING: file.XLSX. PRESS ESCAPE TO CANCEL.
```

file.xlsx is a very large, older workbook that I do not want to be linking to in this specific file I'm opening, but  I'm not sure how it is linked. I've tried checking connections, but haven't found anything.

Where do I look to find all the files linked to in a specific workbook?

Comment: It's your workbook and you have no idea what it's linked to? A link can mean different things. It could be searching for a book that has information needed to complete an action on a cell, for example. Say you have bookB open and it's linked to file.xlsx, there could be a cell with this in bookB.xlsx: `=[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!A1` That's one example. File ->Info ->(check for ussues)Inspect Workbook->Inspect Workbook. This will not point out each link though. You will have to inspect the cells or VB. A toggle for cell inspection for formula is: CTRL+`

Answer (score 1):

If this is the message you are talking about (I dont have enough reputation to comment):

[image]

Then, this happens when you open file.xlsx and it looks for the linked workbook. This is not exactly an error, but a normal process. If it takes long, it is because of the size of the files.

In order to check the linked files just go to following button in the Ribbon:

> Data/Connections/Edit Links

[image]

There you will see what files are linked to the one you are using.